# Creating a function to replace NAs from one data.frame with values from another

Tags: r, na

I regularly have situations where I need to replace missing values from a data.frame with values from some other data.frame that is at a different level of aggregation. So, for example, if I have a data.frame full of county data I might replace NA values with state values stored in another data.frame. After writing the same `merge`... `ifelse(is.na())` yada yada a few dozen times I decided to break down and write a function to do this.

Here's what I cooked up, along with an example of how I use it:

```
fillNaDf <- function(naDf, fillDf, mergeCols, fillCols){
 mergedDf <- merge(naDf, fillDf, by=mergeCols)
 for (col in fillCols){
   colWithNas <- mergedDf[[paste(col, "x", sep=".")]]
   colWithOutNas <- mergedDf[[paste(col, "y", sep=".")]]
   k <- which( is.na( colWithNas ) )
   colWithNas[k] <- colWithOutNas[k]
   mergedDf[col] <- colWithNas
   mergedDf[[paste(col, "x", sep=".")]] <- NULL
   mergedDf[[paste(col, "y", sep=".")]] <- NULL
 }
 return(mergedDf)
}

## test case
fillDf <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,1,2), b = c(3,3,4,4) ,f = c(100,200, 300, 400), g = c(11, 12, 13, 14))
naDf <- data.frame( a = sample(c(1,2), 100, rep=TRUE), b = sample(c(3,4), 100, rep=TRUE), f = sample(c(0,NA), 100, rep=TRUE), g = sample(c(0,NA), 200, rep=TRUE) )
fillNaDf(naDf, fillDf, mergeCols=c("a","b"), fillCols=c("f","g") )
```

So after I got this running I had this odd feeling that someone has probably solved this problem before me and in a much more elegant way. Is there a better/easier/faster solution to this problem? Also, is there a way that eliminates the loop in the middle of my function? That loop is there because I am often replacing NAs in more than one column. And, yes, the function assumes the columns we're filling **from** are named the same and the columns we are filling **to** and the same applies to the merge.

Any guidance or refactoring would be helpful.

***EDIT*** on Dec 2 I realized I had logic flaws in my example which I fixed.

Answer (score 14):

What a great question.

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
# Convert data.frames to data.tables (i.e. data.frames with extra powers;)
library(data.table)
fillDT <- data.table(fillDf, key=c("a", "b"))
naDT <- data.table(naDf, key=c("a", "b"))


# Merge data.tables, based on their keys (columns a & b)
outDT <- naDT[fillDT]    
#      a b  f  g f.1 g.1
# [1,] 1 3 NA  0 100  11
# [2,] 1 3 NA NA 100  11
# [3,] 1 3 NA  0 100  11
# [4,] 1 3  0  0 100  11
# [5,] 1 3  0 NA 100  11
# First 5 rows of 200 printed.

# In outDT[i, j], on the following two lines 
#   -- i is a Boolean vector indicating which rows will be operated on
#   -- j is an expression saying "(sub)assign from right column (e.g. f.1) to 
#        left column (e.g. f)
outDT[is.na(f), f:=f.1]
outDT[is.na(g), g:=g.1]

# Just keep the four columns ultimately needed   
outDT <- outDT[,list(a,b,g,f)]
#       a b  g   f
#  [1,] 1 3  0   0
#  [2,] 1 3 11   0
#  [3,] 1 3  0   0
#  [4,] 1 3 11   0
#  [5,] 1 3 11   0
# First 5 rows of 200 printed.
```

Comment: Cool. Some commentary might help me make sense of it. It looks concise! :)

Comment: OK -- I commented it a bit. If you are interested in learning more, the 'Examples' section of `?data.table` is exemplary, and well worth the ~20 minutes it takes to work through.  Especially if you are a big data guy -- and it looks like you might be -- it could really be worth the up-front time investment.

Comment: this should change to `f:=i.f` and `g:=i.g` now?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a slightly more concise/robust version of your approach.  You could replace the for-loop with a call to `lapply`, but I find the loop easier to read.

This function assumes any columns *not* in `mergeCols` are fair game to have their NAs filled.  I'm not really sure this helps, but I'll take my chances with the voters.

```
fillNaDf.ju <- function(naDf, fillDf, mergeCols) {
  mergedDf <- merge(fillDf, naDf, by=mergeCols, suffixes=c(".fill",""))
  dataCols <- setdiff(names(naDf),mergeCols)
  # loop over all columns we didn't merge by
  for(col in dataCols) {
    rows <- is.na(mergedDf[,col])
    # skip this column if it doesn't contain any NAs
    if(!any(rows)) next
    rows <- which(rows)
    # replace NAs with values from fillDf
    mergedDf[rows,col] <- mergedDf[rows,paste(col,"fill",sep=".")]
  }
  # don't return ".fill" columns
  mergedDf[,names(naDf)]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My preference would be to pull out the code from merge that does the matching and do it myself so that I could keep the ordering of the original data frame intact, both row-wise and column-wise.  I also use matrix indexing to avoid any loops, though to do so I create a new data frame with the revised fillCols and replace the columns of the original with it; I thought I could fill it in directly but apparently you can't use matrix ordering to replace parts of a data.frame, so I wouldn't be surprised if a loop over the names would be faster in some situations.

With matrix indexing:

```
fillNaDf <- function(naDf, fillDf, mergeCols, fillCols) {
  fillB <- do.call(paste, c(fillDf[, mergeCols, drop = FALSE], sep="\r"))
  naB <- do.call(paste, c(naDf[, mergeCols, drop = FALSE], sep="\r"))
  na.ind <- is.na(naDf[,fillCols])
  fill.ind <- cbind(match(naB, fillB)[row(na.ind)[na.ind]], col(na.ind)[na.ind])
  naX <- naDf[,fillCols]
  fillX <- fillDf[,fillCols]
  naX[na.ind] <- fillX[fill.ind]
  naDf[,colnames(naX)] <- naX
  naDf
}
```

With a loop:

```
fillNaDf2 <- function(naDf, fillDf, mergeCols, fillCols) {
  fillB <- do.call(paste, c(fillDf[, mergeCols, drop = FALSE], sep="\r"))
  naB <- do.call(paste, c(naDf[, mergeCols, drop = FALSE], sep="\r"))
  m <- match(naB, fillB)
  for(col in fillCols) {
    fix <- which(is.na(naDf[,col]))
    naDf[fix, col] <- fillDf[m[fix],col]
  }
  naDf
}
```