# Using ifelse() to replace NAs in one data frame by referencing another data frame of different length

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, na

I already reviewed the following two posts and think they *might* answer my question, although I'm struggling to see how:

1) [Conditional replacement of values in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214303/conditional-replacement-of-values-in-a-data-frame)
2) [Creating a function to replace NAs from one data.frame with values from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349909/creating-a-function-to-replace-nas-from-one-data-frame-with-values-from-another)

With that said, I'm trying to replace NAs in one data frame by referencing another data frame of a different (shorter) length and pulling in replacement values from column "B" where the values for column "A" in each data frame match.

I've modified the data, below, for simplicity and illustration, although the concept is the same in the actual data.  FYI, in the real second data frame, there are also no duplicates in column "A".

Here's the first data frame (df1):

```
> df1
    B          C  A
1  NA 2012-10-01  0
2  NA 2012-10-01  5
3   4 2012-10-01 10
4  NA 2012-10-01 15
5  NA 2012-10-01 20
6  20 2012-10-01 25
7  NA 2012-10-01  0
8  NA 2012-10-01  5
9   5 2012-10-01 10
10  5 2012-10-01 15

> str(df1)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ B: num  NA NA 4 NA NA 20 NA NA 5 5
 $ C: Factor w/ 1 level "2012-10-01": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ A: num  0 5 10 15 20 25 0 5 10 15
```

And the second data frame (df2).

```
> df2
   A         B
1  0 1.7169811
2  5 0.3396226
3 10 0.1320755
4 15 0.1509434
5 20 0.0754717
6 25 2.0943396

> str(df2)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  0 5 10 15 20 25
 $ B: num  1.717 0.3396 0.1321 0.1509 0.0755 ...
```

I think I'm pretty close with the following code:

```
> ifelse(is.na(df1$B) == TRUE, df2$B[df2$A == df1$A], df1$B)
 [1]  1.7169811  0.3396226  4.0000000  0.1509434  0.0754717 20.0000000         NA         NA
 [9]  5.0000000  5.0000000
Warning message:
In df2$A == df1$A :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Obviously, I want the 7th and 8th output elements to be 1.7169811 and 0.3396226, rather than NAs . . .

Thanks, in advance, for any help, and, once again, thanks for your patience!

Comment: Not an answer, but `== TRUE` is not necessary in `is.na(df1$B) == TRUE`, since the other arguments in `ifelse` act as the statements when `is.na(df1$B)` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Just an fyi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following code which takes your original statement and makes a small tweak in the `TRUE` argument of the `ifelse` function:

```
> df1$B <- ifelse(is.na(df1$B) == TRUE, df2$B[df2$A %in% df1$A], df1$B)   
#                         Switched '==' to '%in%' ---^
> df1
            B          C  A
1   1.7169811 2012-10-01  0
2   0.3396226 2012-10-01  5
3   4.0000000 2012-10-01 10
4   0.1509434 2012-10-01 15
5   0.0754717 2012-10-01 20
6  20.0000000 2012-10-01 25
7   1.7169811 2012-10-01  0
8   0.3396226 2012-10-01  5
9   5.0000000 2012-10-01 10
10  5.0000000 2012-10-01 15
```

Comment: @ccapizzano  Awesome.  Thank you, sir!  I had a feeling %in% might have had something to do with it.  I felt like Voldemort in the 7th book when he's in the shrieking shack:  "Soooo, close.  Sooo close."  Thanks, again.

Comment: @ccapizzano how would i change this ifelse statement to replace NAs where the values in more than one column are a match i.e. column A and C?

Answer (score 7):

You may also use:

```
df1$B[is.na(df1$B)] <- df2$B[match(df1$A[is.na(df1$B)],df2$A)]
df1

#             B          C  A
# 1   1.7169811 2012-10-01  0
# 2   0.3396226 2012-10-01  5
# 3   4.0000000 2012-10-01 10
# 4   0.1509434 2012-10-01 15
# 5   0.0754717 2012-10-01 20
# 6  20.0000000 2012-10-01 25
# 7   1.7169811 2012-10-01  0
# 8   0.3396226 2012-10-01  5
# 9   5.0000000 2012-10-01 10
# 10  5.0000000 2012-10-01 15
```

Comment: This seems like the most typical R-ish way to me. +1

Comment: @thelatemail, why would you say this is the most "R-ish" way?

Comment: @DanielFletcher - just my subjective opinion - the answer uses simple subsetting and the pretty basic building block `match` function. I could see the answer being used in an introductory textbook.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks.  I'm currently taking a bunch of introductory _courses_ via the [Johns Hopkins Data Science Specialization on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/specialization/jhudatascience/1)  What are some introductory textbooks you'd recommend?  Thanks, again.

Comment: @thelatemail.  Good deal. Thanks!  By the way, how do I say "thanks" to someone without breaking the stackoverflow etiquette of "don't just say 'thanks' in a comment, newb!"?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1[is.na(df1$B), c('A','C','B')] <- merge(df1[is.na(df1$B), -1], df2, by = 'A')
```